# Best way to develop this function in react js instead of this current .map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

first of all i am new to all this, so apologies. I am trying to develop a search function, now i have developed it but as to my app there is a problem.

The search function which is in my header component is rendered like this in my index

```
<Header course={course}/>
```

which does not work as i get "cannot get property of slug" which is here in the header component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  ShoppingCartIcon,
  MenuIcon,
  SearchIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import * as Realm from "realm-web";

const Header = ({course}) => {
  const {slug } = course;
  const router = useRouter();
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [autoComplete, setAutoComplete] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    if (searchTerm.length) {
      // add your Realm App Id to the .env.local file
      const REALM_APP_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REALM_APP_ID;
      const app = new Realm.App({ id: REALM_APP_ID });
      const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
      try {
        const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
        const searchAutoComplete = await user.functions.searchAutoComplete(
          searchTerm
        );
        setAutoComplete(() => searchAutoComplete);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    } else {
      setAutoComplete([]);
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setSearchTerm("");
    router.push({
      pathname: `/search/${searchTerm}`,
    });
  };

  const handleSelect = (id) => {
    setSearchTerm("");
    router.push({
      pathname: `/course/${slug}`,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                className="w-full border rounded-md pl-10 pr-4 py-2 focus:border-green-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search"
                onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                value={searchTerm}
              />
            </form>
            {autoComplete.length > 0 && (
              <ul className="absolute inset-x-0 top-full bg-green-200 border border-green-500 rounded-md z-20">
                {autoComplete.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                    <li
                      key={item.slug}
                      className="px-4 py-2 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer"
                      onClick={() => handleSelect(item.slug)}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </li>
                    </>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
     
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Now in my index file it should be something like this:

```
 <Header course={course}/>
```

But i have to put it in a map function and it does not work properly like that,

```
  {courses.map((course) => (
                <div className="col-md-4">
                 {/* <Cards course={course} /> */}
                 <Header course={course}/>
                </div>
            ))}
```

So can you guys tell me or show me what type of function i need to use so that my identifiers, args whatever can work and my search index with slug will work

Comment: Are your passing `slug` with course object? OR course object contain `slug` parameter?

Comment: What are the contents of the `courses` array? What format does each `course` have?

Comment: @Mohammed the course object contains the slug, i just want to render the header component one time instead of mapping it for each course using the .map function

Comment: As per my understanding, your requirement is like within header of website there Search functionality and when user will type there then there will be auto complete suggestion will pop up. This auto complete suggestion is courses and this courses is coming from index.js file (from `<Header />` componnent ). Am I getting it correct ?

Comment: @Mohammed yes sir

Comment: The correct method of implementation is create a seprate components which will contain the suggests list and pass the course array as props in that component instead of passing to header.  Apply the loop over courses slugs and render your `li`. Once your done with this then show this component in place of your auto complete logic

Comment: If you don't get this ask me, I will explain you again Better

Comment: alright let me try this, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This way may bring you closer to the answer, But make sure there is slug in
courses

```
{courses.map(({ slug }) => (
        <div className="col-md-4">
           <Header course={slug}/>
         </div>
 ))}
```

and in component Header :

```
const Header = ({slug}) => {
  console.log(slug)
...
}
```

Comment: the course object contains the slug, i just want to render the header component one time instead of mapping it for each course using the .map function

Comment: ok,It seems that you have to pass your courses as props to the header component and do it inside the header map.

Comment: yeah but i dont want to use the .map because it then shows header for each product, is there any way to do it and have just one of them ??